# Ansible - how to register a variable and also using async together?

Tags: ansible

It seems I'm not able to register a variable whilst using async in the same task. What I'm trying to do is running a check in parallel to see if multiple services have finished completed before executing the next task. However if I have async mode on, the register variable contains information on the async job status rather than the json I'm expecting. If I take off async then it works fine.

```
- name: Get infos on container
  docker_container_info:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - service1
    - service2
    - service3
  async: 30
  poll: 0
  until: result.stdout.find("completed") != -1
  retries: 5
  delay: 10
  register: result

- name: Run next task
  command: echo done
  .....
  .....
```

I don't really need to check the job status but just the json of each item that is returned from docker_container_info but want async on. How do I get them to work together?

Comment: Unfortunately the way Ansible handles async doesn't solve your problem. You can execute the task in parallel(just for efficiency) and once it is completed, get results in next task. You can refer to following answer (Option 3) https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/5023

Comment: That won't work in my use case as I need to re-run the task with the until loop ( in parallel) until it finds a particular string. I've exhausted all options to my knowledge and I've come to conclusion it cannot be done but would like to be proven wrong!! I can check the status using aync_status but there is no way for it to re-run the task even if I get the output in results_file from async_status

Comment: Okay, there is another method, but, it is not straightforward, When you fire/ trigger an async, register the result. In the async task's result you have something like "results_file": "/var/lib/awx/.ansible_async/577796854780.28". That is the file that has the 'actual' result as and when it happens in the async task. So, in your next task you can 'keep reading' the file 'until' a 'string' is 'present' in the result_file

Comment: Basically, you are keeping track of a file, that is being updated in parallel by the 'async task' using another task. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I also tried that to no avail.

```

Comment: The problem is that if I use async, I have nothing to go on in the first task to retry the task. The results variable will not contain output of docker_container_info but the ansible_job_id, results_file location etc so until: result.stdout.find("completed") != -1 would not work. Inside the results_file will only contain the output of the the first task (which would have only ran once) which would unlikely to contain the string "completed" in such a short duration of time

Comment: Is there a way I can grep or search inside a file in an until loop? It would have to be inside the same task so cannot be a lineinfile etc In pseudocode:

until: "completed" in item.results_file
retries: 5
delay: 10

where results_file is the file location containing the real output of the first task. If it can be done, then this may work!

Comment: Might not be possible, basically you need the 'result_file' (volatile name) to grep it inside **the script**, and the result_file will be set only after the 'async_task aka, **the script**' has started.